# If $A$ and $B$ are proper classes, how to prove that $A \cup B$ is a proper class?.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A\cup B=\{x:x\in A \lor x\in B\}$,

if $A\cup B\in A\cup B$ then $A\cup B \in A \lor A\cup B \in B$

But i don't see how to get the contradiction. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well $A$ is included in $A \cup B$, and a set cannot included a proper class, ergo $A\cup B$ is a proper class.

Comment: I haven't seen that, with what you have said i can prove it like this:
Suppose that $A\cup B$ is a set, by properties, $A$ is a subset of $A\cup B$, as $A \cup B$ is a set, by an axiom $A$ is a set, but by hypothesis $A$ is a proper class, then $A \cup B$ is a proper class.

Thanks.

Comment: As a stylistic comment, your use of proof by contradiction is inappropriate here.

Comment: But, i was used reductio ad absurdum.

Comment: Yes. "Reductio ad absurdum" is the Latin name for the proof method that in English is also called "proof by contradiction". You used it inappropriately here. A proof is a chain of implications. If you find a chain starting at $P$ and ending at $Q$, then you have a direct proof of $P\rightarrow Q$, not an indirect proof by contradiction. If you add assumption $\neg Q$ to th beginning of your chain, then derive $P\rightarrow Q$, then add the deduction $Q\wedge\neg Q$, the proof appears in the form of reductio ad absurdum. But it was already a direct proof without the addition of those two lines.

Comment: It's a common mistake to turn a direct proof into a proof by contradiction unnecessarily. It is better proof writing style to avoid doing so. If your proof remains valid after deleting the first and last line, it's not really a proof by contradiction and should be rewritten to reflect this.

Comment: I gave you a direct proof in my answer. In your comment you added statements to turn it into a proof by contradiction. Do not do this.